# Different windows 8.1 and 10 apps with same package name

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

Is it possible to have two separate apps, one for windows 8.1 and one for windows 10 under the same package name in the windows store? What I mean is, if a user is on windows 10 they will see the windows 10 version of the app in the store, and if they are using windows 8.1, they'll see the 8.1 version of the app.

AS of right now, I have a uwp app in the store. I am currently in the process of creating a windows 8.1 app and it needs to have the same reserved name as the uwp one.

Answer (score 0):

The highest version numbered package that is compatible with the Client OS is installed.

So, if you have: MyApp 1.0 (UWP), MyApp 1.0 (8.1 Universal) then your Windows customers will get the UWP version, and your Windows 8.1 customers get the 8.1 version.

If you have: MyApp 1.0 (UWP), MyApp 1.1 (8.1 Universal), then your Windows 10 customers will get the 8.1 version, not the UWP version.